How do I add caching in create vite extra?
I'm implementing caching in a create-vite-extra project using lru-cache. My goal is to cache rendered HTML and serve it from the cache when available. The cache is defined and used in the *all route handler as shown below:
// server/app.ts

const cache = new LRUCache({
    ttl: 1000 * 60 * 60,
    max: 100,
});

In the *all handler, I check if the cache has the requested URL and return the cached HTML if available. Otherwise, I render the app, save the output to the cache, and send it to the client:
if (cache.has(url)) {
    res.set({'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(cache.get(url));
    return;
}

const {pipe, abort} = render(
    url,
    queryClient,
    dehydratedState,
    {
        onShellReady() {
            res.status(200);
            res.set({'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

            const transformStream = new Transform({
                transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
                    res.write(chunk, encoding);
                    callback();
                },
            });

            const [htmlStart, htmlEnd] = template.split(`<!--app-html-->`);

            res.write(htmlStart);

            transformStream.on('finish', () => {
                cache.set(url, htmlStart + htmlEnd);
                res.end(htmlEnd);
            });

            pipe(transformStream);
        },
        // ...
    }
);

The issue is that when I run the app, the browser renders the app's state (window.REACT_QUERY_STATE) instead of the actual HTML. The rendered page looks incomplete or broken.
I'm not sure if the problem is with:
How the HTML template is being processed (template.split or vite.transformIndexHtml).
The caching logic (cache.set storing incomplete/incorrect content).
How the React Query state (window.REACT_QUERY_STATE) is being injected.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or knows how to fix this?
